# Unit testing JPA queries

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, orm

How should I unit test a method that returns a boolean value and is implemented like so?

```
return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT(i) FROM Items i WHERE o.id=:id", Long.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult() == 1;
```

`entityManager` is injected into the class.

I think I probably should verify that `createQuery` gets called with this query and then `setParameter` gets called with `id` and then result is compared to 1. However, isn't such a test a bit overkill for a simple line of code like this?
I especially feel uncomfortable using the whole select statement in unit test. It seems more like implementation detail to me. However, what other way is there to check that the query actually check item COUNT and does something else?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you have that method as part of some sort of Repository class.

I would suggest leaving the Repository layer out of the unit testing suite.
In general you should not have any logic inside your repository methods (trivial if any) or you should at least strive for that.

From my personal experience, you should end up with some integration testing suite on top of your unit tests and the Repository methods were always first on my list when it comes to integration testing and were the base for the rest of the IT tests.

The only exception that i can think of is when you build your query conditionally with the use of Criteria API.. but again, its better to focus on integration testing that properly also.

Thats my advice but the call is yours in the end..

Comment: Just a general rule of thumb to add to this (correct) answer: test the code at the boundary of your application (application - DB in this case) with integration tests; test any code that only relies on other 'pieces' of your app with unit tests

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing SQL statements in a Java program is more difficult because you are crossing "unit" boundaries. The traditional definition of a unit is that it is a single class under test. However, that is not very useful as it is an all-or-nothing classification that creates a huge gap in your test coverage, for no benefit. It is better to extend your unit testing tools with support for composed units that have to work together reliably.

One approach is to create a mock that checks the parameters passed and passes an appropriate return value. That doesn't, however, check the logic or calculation. It may be a necessary first step.

Another approach is to use an in-memory database that understands the kind of SQL you are using, and can be populated with the data you need at the start of each test or session. This will test much deeper into your design and code than mocking return values. It validates your syntax and your semantics, while being extremely fast, one of the most useful attributes of unit tests.